# C++11 Threading: Object with arguments in the constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I've been reading a lot lately about C++, but one thing doesn't come up. I ended up finding a solution of my own but I'm not exactly sure it is the right one. So I'm asking if there is a better way than this. From what I read in C++11 starting a thread is a simple job, and in fact I didn't find it all that hard. Then I tried to improve my knowledge with a shot in the dark, so I decided to "turn classes into threads" (if that makes sense). Basically I would have a class that will do its own thing, unbothered by the main program. Here's some code to guide you through

**SocketServer.h**

```
#ifndef SOCKETSERVER_H
#define SOCKETSERVER_H

#include <string>
#include <boost\asio.hpp>

class SocketServer
{
public:
    SocketServer(std::string ip_address, unsigned short port);
    ~SocketServer();

    void Read();
    //bool isValidIP(const char* ip_address);

private:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    std::string listenIP;
    unsigned short listenPort;
    void BeginListen();
};


#endif;
```

now in my main() func whenever I try

```
std::thread socketServerThread(SocketServer, listenIP, listenPort);
```

It always explodes in my face. But If I have that structure

```
void InitSocketServer(std::string listenIP, unsigned short listenPort)
{
    SocketServer* c = new SocketServer(listenIP, listenPort);
}
```

And I put that in the thread constructor WITH the arguments, it suddenly works. For me personally that is messy code and I'm wondering if there is better way to achieve this same goal. Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to construct the `SocketServer` instance somewhere. Where do you want that to happen? And what will be responsible for managing the lifetime of the `SocketServer` instance?

Comment: "Turning classes into threads" makes as much sense as turning a TV station into a wind turbine. They're not even comparable things...

Answer (score 2):

The usual solution is to give the object a `start` or `run` method that does the real work. You can then create a new instance with `new` and spawn a thread to call the `start` or `run` method on it.

Two issues you have to keep in mind though:

1. You either need to `detach` the thread or someone needs to `join` it.
2. If you allocate the instance with `new`, someone needs to `delete` it when you're done.

You can make the thread a member of the class if you want. Just don't try to actually create the thread in the constructor because the object isn't yet fully constructed until the constructor returns. So do it in the `start` or `run` method if you want the object to manage the lifetime of the thread.

Comment: Yes but the question is, how do I pass arguments to that object so it would work. As you can see I'm passing a listen ip and a listen port. I tried many ways and I just don't see how I can do that :|

The only solution I can come up with is that void function that I pasted earlier which creates the object. I made "BeginListen()" public and it is still unaccessible from the thread context. x.x

Comment: You can put them in member variables of the object that you set when you construct the object. Or you can make them parameters to the `start` or `run` function and then use `std::bind` to pass them to the thread.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is what I ended up with (if somebody else wonders)


`SocketServer srv;
 std::thread socketServerThread(&SocketServer::BeginListen, &srv, listenIP, listenPort);
 socketServerThread.detach();`